# Distance, time and speed problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> The distance between $A$ and $B$ is $3$ km. A cyclist starts from $A$ towards $B$ at $v_1=27$ km/h. At the same time, another cyclist starts from $B$ and travels towards $A$ at $18$ km/h. After what time do they meet? How far is the meeting from $A$?

If $t=x$, then $s_1=27x$ and $s_2=18x$.

$s_1+s_2=3$; $27x+18x=3$; $x=\dfrac{3}{45}=\dfrac{1}{15}$ hours.

Is this the right answer?

Comment: It is better to mention the meaning of different variables to know what you are doing

Comment: Two objects which are distance $d$ km apart from each other and start travelling towards each other with speed $v_1$ kmph and $v_2$ kmph will meet after $t=\frac {d}{v_1+v_2}$ hr.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. You forgot the time unit (hour). And it would have been better if you had simplified the answer, getting $\frac1{15}$ hours (or 4 minutes).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. And for the second question, the answer is $\dfrac{27}{15}=\dfrac{9}{5}$ $km$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.